# GAE -> Error: Number of API configs allowed on ... is 25

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoint

I'm creating an GAE application (Java) with Eclipse. Locally everything works, but if I try to deploy the application to the server, a GEA log shows following error:

> E 1970-01-16 21:33:26.331 Endpoints:
>   https://37-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/rangevariants@v1 Error:
>   Number of API configs allowed on 37-dot-myapp.appspot.com is 25;
>   already reached 25.

Until a few weeks ago I never had problems like this. I updated the SDK because it didn't create the config api of an endpoint anymore. Until now, there were never any problems with any limits.

Can I have some explanation and a solution?

---

I re-copy the error:

> 2013-06-03 09:50:37.604 /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages 204 224ms 0kb E 1970-01-16 21:37:25.837 Endpoints: https://38-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/store@v1 Error: Number of API configs allowed on 38-dot-myapp.appspot.com is 25; already reached 25

The first date is right, but the second date is wrong and I think it is created by GAE. How can I fix this?  Has Google added the limit of 25 endpoints with the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: The time seems off - the year 1970? Maybe this is causing your problem?

Comment: I don't think so I have this same error with a log date time stamp that is current (not to mention this comes app engine and not our code as it is). This seems to be a limitation from Google on Endpoints, maybe one of the Endpoint engineers can comment?

Answer (score 2):

I am suspecting that you have generated your endpoint classes from entities using the plugin.
If that is the case, then you have every endpoint configured as a separate api. If you check the `@Api` annotation of every class you will find then having different `name`s like this :

```
@Api(name = "FirstEntityEndpoint", ...)

@Api(name = "SecondEntityEndpoint", ...)
```

and so on.
The error message is saying you can have max 25 apis in your app and I doubt you really need all these apis. All you have to do is to configure all `@Api` annotations to use the same `name` . For example :

```
@Api(name = "MyEndpoint", ...)
```

If you do this you will not only solve your problem but also have the generation much faster. 
If this solves your problem, you better make a base class for all your endpoint classes and let this class only have `@Api` annotation. All subclasses will inherit it and work fine.